# creating python function to return value

Tags: python, function

I have written a function called "adjust", so what it needs to do is to take user input from 0 to 9 and to retune either 0,5 or 10.

My function has come across a syntax error when it runs until "elif", But I can't figure out what I did wrong.
This is what I have now ( I try to use control K to post the code but if keep giving me an error)

```
cents = []
def adjust(cents):
    c=0
    for i in cents:
        x=cents.index(i)
        if(i==1 or i==2): 
            j=0
            elif(i==3 or i==4 or i==6 or i==7): 
                j=5
                elif(i ==8 or i==9):
                    j = 10
                    else:
                        j=i
                        return cents


n=int(input("Enter a number of cents between 0 and 9:))
#haven't figure out how to put the user input into my function
```

The example output would be:

input 1 , output 0
input 4, output 5
input 8, output 10

Comment: I believe that elif should have the same indentation as their previous if/elif

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is indentation.
In Python, indentation is used to indicate the scope of the operation.
In your case, your `elif` is inside the `if` and thus raises a Syntax error, as there was no `if` before it in the same scope.

Simply fixing your indentation will solve the issue.
However, your code could also be written a bit cleaner (and I am assuming you want to return the modified versions, not the originals), so my version would be:

```py
def adjust(cents):
    # Make copy of provided cents to modify
    adj_cents = list(cents)

    # Loop over all cents and round all values to nearest 5
    for i, x in enumerate(adj_cents):
        if x in (1, 2): 
            adj_cents[i] = 0
        elif x in (3, 4, 6, 7): 
            adj_cents[i] = 5
        elif x in (8, 9):
            adj_cents[i] = 10

    # Return adj_cents
    return(adj_cents)


n=int(input("Enter a number of cents between 0 and 9:))
#haven't figure out how to put the user input into my function
```

If you finish writing your script, you will be able to provide an iterable of `cents` you want to adjust to the function, which will return you the adjusted ones.
No need to call it iteratively.

Comment: I am just thinking I have to put c as 0 first. and the user will have a input between 0 and 9, and according the user input then it print out the outcome that I want within the function.Any idea to help finish the remaining part?

Comment: Thank You I will go have a try and figure out how to call the function out with the user input.

Comment: @OMGC Good luck. Make sure to mark the appropriate response as the answer to mark this question as complete.

Comment: How do I call this function along with the user input "n"? 
By doing this `adjust(cents,n)`  ?

Comment: That is for you to decide. You will have to collect all the user input into an iterable outside of the function and then simply call the function with it. The `adjust` function is fully independent of any user input. It simply requires an iterable of 'cents' values that need adjusting. Where that iterable comes from does not matter.

Comment: Hum... I try putting this `print("After rounding off the number is:" + adjust(n))` after my input code, but it came up with an error, what am I missing? I was thinking it will work with the function with user input 'n'.

Comment: You have to give it an iterable of integers, not a single integer. After all, you wrote a loop, so you want an iterable. We are not here to solve every tiny detail of a problem, only the general details. It is up to you to figure the rest out.